# Finding Extrema in an Image without dividing into Regions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to find the 8-point extrema of an binary Image. I know about 'Extrema' Property of Regionprops function in Matlab. However, this function is dividing the image into Region first and then it is trying to find out the extrema. Is there anyway to find the extrema in Image without dividing it into region? Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well you need a binary image to do it right? What do you mean by "dividing the image into region" ? Binarize it?

Comment: No, I already have a binary image. What I am telling is Regionprops is finding the extrema from each of connected component in binary image. I want the extrema for the whole image.

Comment: Cant you get those and the get the max/min value among them? (just asking)

Comment: Yeah, that can be done. I was thinking of some good approach for these or some inbuilt function. However, going forward with this.